# What do you call a helmet that covers the entire face?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a helmet that covers the entire face?

[image]

By helmet, I mean mostly medieval helmets worn by soldiers. Not helmet you wear when you ride a motorcycle although I doubt it would make any difference in this question. I am not talking about the specific helmet in the picture, but helmets in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "closed helmet" or "close helmet' refers in general to one that covers the face except for a small eye opening, such as the one in the picture. "Open helmet" or "open helm" is used for one that exposes much of the face. See the [Wikipedia article on "Close Helmet"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_helmet) Links from this article describe and depict many types of helmets, open and closed, such as the open [nasal helment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_helmet)

There were many individual terms for specific designs or types of closed helmet, each with a specific name, as the answer by Shino correctly indicates.

Answer (score 1):

During medieval times, the name of the helmet worn by a solider depended entirely on the design. A quick search of the picture you have posted above suggests the name of this helmet in particular is a Visored Bascinet.

Other helmets that covered a solider's face included:

- Great Helm
- Bascinet
- Barbute
- Armet

All these helmets vary by design. A google search should give you pictures of them. Outside of medieval times however, I don't think there is a specific name. Most are generally known as a helmet or a full-face helmet.